# Failed to read values in CFPrefsPlistSource

Tags: xcode, vapor, get-request

I write cocoa-app and using Vapor . After starting the server i do get-request from  the application. And and I get a message:
    [User Defaults] Failed to read values in   CFPrefsPlistSource<0x6080000e7500> (Domain: com.apple.PowerManagement,  User: kCFPreferencesAnyUser, ByHost: Yes, Container: (null)): accessing  preferences outside an application's container requires user-preference-read or file-read-data sandbox access, detaching from cfprefsd
    I'm try change SandBox settings, update Xcode(current version is 9.2), create App Groups, reboot my computer. Nothing helps.
   If someone faced with a similar error - please help.